# Український відповідник до слова "криптовалюта"

Tags: вибір-слова, відповідник

[Криптовалюта](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B0) (від англ. Cryptocurrency) — вид цифрової валюти, емісія та облік якої засновані на асиметричному шифруванні і застосуванні різних криптографічних методів захисту. Сьогодні ми можемо часто зустріти це слово в Інтернеті, і тому цікавить чи є до нього якийсь український відповідник.

Якщо частину "currency" вже перекладено, то незрозуміло як бути із "сrypto", що перекладається в Гугл перекладачі як "крипто", тобто щось таєме (накшталт слова "[крипта](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0)", що дослівно можна перекласти як "тайник" або "критий підземний хід"). Однак слова "крипто" в СУМі немає.

Також я перевірив інформацію на [Словотворі](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/kryptovaliuta), там пропонують такі варіанти як "тайногроші" або "тайноміна", однак поки-що жодний варіант там не вибраний як правильний, та й СУМ показує слово "тайна" як те, яке рідко вживається. Також на Вікіпедії наткнувся на статтю "[Електронний карбованець](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8C_(%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B0))" (українська криптовалюта), тому подумав, що можливо можна буде перекласти "криптовалюту" як "електровалюту", однак можливо тоді може виникнути плутанина між цим словом, та коштами які знаходяться на онлайн рахунках.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я не розумію, чому Ви згодні на частину *-валюта*, але хочете позбутися частини *крипто-* — адже вони обидві іншомовного походження (*крипто-* — від давньогрецького *κρυπτός* «прихований», *-валюта* — від італійського *valuta* «цінність, вартість, валюта»).

У «Словнику української мови» в 11 томах є [*валю́та*](http://sum.in.ua/s/valjuta), є там і слова на *крипто-*: [*криптогра́ма*, *криптогра́фія*, *криптографі́чний*, *крипто́нім*](http://sum.in.ua/p/4/348/2). Також в українській мові очевидно існують й інші слова на *крипто-*: *криптоана́ліз*, *криптозооло́гія*, *криптосисте́ма* — не внесені у СУМ-11, мабуть, через його давнину.

У «Словнику української мови» в 20 томаж є й конкретно [*криптовалю́та*](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=221251&page=1430) (як і перша частина складних слів [*крипто…*](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=205703&page=1431) загалом).

Є й словосполучення [*електронна валюта* та *цифрова валюта*](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B0) (синонімічні), що однак є гіперонімами для *криптовалюти* (*криптовалюта* — частковий випадок *цифрової/електронної валюти*).

Answer (score 1):

[Словник Штепи](https://ia902801.us.archive.org/8/items/shtepa1977/shtepa1977.PDF)

> крипто… – таємно…
> криптографія – таємничопис

Зустрічаєть ся, причім в СУМ-11, також складнословотвір з *тайно…*:

> [тайнопис](http://sum.in.ua/s/tajnopys), у, *чол*.
>
> Те саме, що [криптографія](http://sum.in.ua/s/kryptoghrafija). *Якщо вам доведеться коли-небудь побачити в ломоносовському архіві у Ленінграді лабораторні журнали геніального російського вченого і поета, вам здасться, що вони написані нікому не зрозумілим тайнописом. Справа втому, що в ті часи хімічних формул ще не було і різні речовини зображались умовними позначками* (Наука і життя, 4, 1965, 25).

І, далебі, як Sasha зауважив, *валюта* теж непитоме для украӥньської.

Тут пан Штепа радить:

> валюта - чужігроші

Отже матимемо **таємногроші** або **тайногроші**.